# how to track user search activity on website in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-search, modern

I am owner of shrepoint website and i have implemented modern search using pnp modern search plugin

Now i have requirement, i have to store what user has searched for in a list (need to store search string along with timestamp in a list)

how to do that, please help

Answer (score 0):

**View search usage report:**

- Sign in the **SharePoint admin center** as SharePoint admins or Global admins
- Under **Settings** tab, select **Search & Intelligence**.
  [image]
- On the Search & Intelligence page, select **Insights**.
  [image]

**Overview of Search reports**

[image]

More information, please refer to this article: [View search usage reports](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/view-search-usage-reports)